# FIREWIRE - Windows XP - No audio? not recognized as audio source?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, webcam, firewire

I have a sony camcorder i'm connecting to windows XP via firewire.
Windows XP recognizes the camera as a video source, but not as an audio source.
i.e. it does not show up as an option in the drop down list of microphones.

Curiously, it was working at some point in the past and now just suddenly doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know how i go about fixing this?

thanks

Comment: What model camcorder?  What software are you using (native XP apps, or something from Sony?)

Comment: camera: sony dcr-vx2100
trying to stream camera over web using flash. in the flash options camera does not show up as audio source now, but it worked in the past.